# Allow moving windows past the top of the screen

Tags: windows-10, display

I have an application which is windowed, but I would like to fake a full screen.  By that, I mean I want to move the top above the screen so the display begins below the title bar.  I can move the window using the built in "Move" option (next to Minimize, Maximize, etc).  The problem is that when I try to move it above the screen, it will automatically pop back down.  However, moving past the screen works for left, right, and bottom, so I'm hoping there is a way to go past the top as well.